# jquery toggle button add remove class

Tags: jquery, button, checkbox

I have tried to follow the specs on jquery documentation but i cannot initialize the label of the button programmatically and add/remove classes to it.

Please have a look at the few lines in this jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/akinod/2/edit

**HTML**

```
<label for="xAxisToggleBtn"></label>
<input type="checkbox" id="xAxisToggleBtn"/>
```

**CSS**

```
.on {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;   
}

.off {
    background-color:brown;
    color: white;   
}
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(window).load(function() {

      $("#xAxisToggleBtn").button();


      $('#xAxisToggleBtn').die('click').live('click', function(){

                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Turn Off');

                  //why I cannot add/remove classes to change the theme?
                    $(this).addClass('on');
                    $(this).removeClass('off');

                } else {
                    $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Turn On');

                   //why I cannot initialize add/remove classes to change the theme?
                    $(this).addClass('off');
                    $(this).removeClass('on');

                }
        });

});


//why I cannot initialize the label here?
$("#xAxisToggleBtn").button('option', 'label', 'Turn Off');
$("#xAxisToggleBtn").attr('checked', true);
$("#xAxisToggleBtn").addClass('on');
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the jQuery.toggleClass method - http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Yes, I tried and did not work. Their functional behaviour is the same. Add/remove does this explicitly so the issue is not in not using toggleClass.Thanks

Comment: what is the issue are you facing?

Comment: @Ashirvad Singh: the issue is described in the comments in jsbin link in my question. Thanks

Comment: And yet we prefer to have a full question here, on Stack Overflow, with the question, the problem(s) you're facing and the relevant code. Otherwise the question becomes useless in the event of JS Bin becoming unreachable.

Comment: @David: good point, have edited the question

Comment: @Gian : updated my answer depending on that you are using button plugin of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the class to the button widget, your styles will need to overwrite jQuery-UI own, and make sure the elements are loaded before you try to manipulate them.

```
$(function() {
    $("#xAxisToggleBtn").attr('checked', true)
      .addClass('on').button({'label': 'Turn Off'})
      .button('widget')
      .addClass('off');        

      $('#xAxisToggleBtn').on('click', function(){                
                if($(this).is(':checked')){
                    $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Turn Off');
                } else {
                    $(this).button('option', 'label', 'Turn On');
                }
                $(this).button('widget').toggleClass('on off');
        });

});
```

```css
.on {
    background: green!important;
    color: white!important;    
}

.off {
    background:brown !important;
    color: white !important;    
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/TCycA/)

Answer (score 1):

I made changes here again: http://jsfiddle.net/5g2Y6/2/

Note : this is a hack.  The button plugin doesnt have any option for css.  Please look more for the documentation of button plugin.

PS : Dont use "live" method its deprecated.   Use jquery "on" method.

Comment: Thanks. The add/remove class does not appear to work here. Do you see the background of the button to switch between brown and green (as per CSS) when toggled? Thanks